# Failed to interpret .npz file .npz as pickle? np.load(allow pickle = true) not working?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I've been running into this weird error while trying to load up some datasets... I'm not sure what's causing this error as the files I have are .npz files and they "should" be loaded up just fine by np.load(file, allow_pickle = true). Any clue on how to fix?

Here's what I'm talking about(this is from cs231n project btw):

```
def load_imagenet_val(num=None):
    """Load a handful of validation images from ImageNet.

    Inputs:
    - num: Number of images to load (max of 25)

    Returns:
    - X: numpy array with shape [num, 224, 224, 3]
    - y: numpy array of integer image labels, shape [num]
    - class_names: dict mapping integer label to class name
    """
    imagenet_fn = 'cs682/datasets/imagenet_val_25.npz'
    if not os.path.isfile(imagenet_fn):
      print('file %s not found' % imagenet_fn)
      print('Run the following:')
      print('cd cs682/datasets')
      print('bash get_imagenet_val.sh')
      assert False, 'Need to download imagenet_val_25.npz'
    f = np.load(imagenet_fn, allow_pickle = True)
    X = f['X']
    y = f['y']
    class_names = f['label_map'].item()
    if num is not None:
        X = X[:num]
        y = y[:num]
    return X, y, class_names
```

when running the above function, I get the following trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    459             try:
--> 460                 return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
    461             except Exception:

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-4043844dfc8d> in <module>
      1 from cs682.data_utils import load_imagenet_val
----> 2 X, y, class_names = load_imagenet_val(num=5)
      3 
      4 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
      5 for i in range(5):

~/CS682/assignment3/cs682/data_utils.py in load_imagenet_val(num)
    253       print('bash get_imagenet_val.sh')
    254       assert False, 'Need to download imagenet_val_25.npz'
--> 255     f = np.load(imagenet_fn, allow_pickle = True)
    256     X = f['X']
    257     y = f['y']

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    461             except Exception:
    462                 raise IOError(
--> 463                     "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
    464     finally:
    465         if own_fid:

OSError: Failed to interpret file 'cs682/datasets/imagenet_val_25.npz' as a pickle
```

Comment: how was initially the file `'cs682/datasets/imagenet_val_25.npz'` saved?

Comment: Without access to the file, I don't think we can diagnose the problem.  And it's likely that file is too big to down load and test.  You may need to talk with other people working with this particular (or related) dataset.

Comment: @hpaulj this dataset is available publicly through this link http://cs231n.stanford.edu/imagenet_val_25.npz.
It's around 8.3mb

Comment: Got it to work! Somehow, the bash command to get the dataset only downloads around 12kb of the original data which is 8mb... werid..